# Problemas al realizar el debug en VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, iis

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema con el VS20222 versión 4.8.09032. Tengo publicado un Api (Net core c#) en el IIS local, corro mi local host y desde el VS en la opción "Debug" selecciono la opción "Attach to process", selecciono un proceso "w3wp.exe" que le corresponde a mi aplicación, cuando ejecuto el endpoint que deseo debugear el proceso se detiene en el punto de interrupción que tengo aplicado pero cuando presiono el F10 y avanzo unas cuantas líneas el proceso de debug se regresa nuevamente al punto de interrupción donde se inicio el debug preciono F10 y se va a otra línea, el debug se empieza a realizar de manera desordenada no respetando el avance línea tras línea. Como puedo solucionar esto?? tengo estas opciones en mi configuración